# SQL Server 2008 and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, northwind

I have problem with my VS 2012.

I have installed SQL Server 2008. The next step in what I did was to install `SQL2000SampleDb.msi` (Northwind). On the command line, I installed everything, by this steps:

```
cd "C:\SQL Server 2000 Sample Databases"
sqlcmd -S .\sqlexpress -i instnwd.sql
```

Request:

- `Change database content to 'master'.`
- `Change database content to 'Northwind'.`

3 step: `sqlcmd -S .\sqlexpress`, and:

```
use northwind
select LastName from employees
go
```

and all was ok... but if I want to connect with VS I have problem. I'm creating a Windows Forms Application

-> menu: Project -> Add New Data Source -> select Database -> Dataset.

And now I can't see any connection to select, I have only the view:

http://pl.tinypic.com/r/1433rt3/8

and the second way which I did was such:

```
View -> server explorer -> PPM on Data connection -> "Add Connection" 
     -> Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient)
```

and server name `W-Komputer`, when I wanted to select a database this error appears:

http://i60.tinypic.com/2exvuir.png

I tried this way, but not any effects: (please search in google: How to: Install Sample Databases - I haven't 10 reputation :( and I can't add more that 2 links)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `W-Komputer\sqlexpress` as this is the name of the instance if Sql on your computer.

The `.` when you are using sqlcmd is referring to your computer/localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Try enable remote connection on Sql Server Configuration Manger.

Follow this step : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx